# Status e-mail - nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

Sempre que envio uma mensagem utilizando a nodemailer tenho como obter a messageId exemplo :

> messageId: a49157fb-cf04-d913-5dec-726d939fac97@gmail.com

É possivel fazer uma consulta para checar o status desse e-mail ? tal como se já foi aberto, se foi realmente recebido, etc... 
Utilizo no momento a nodemailer em nodejs porém posso migra pra qualquer plataforma / linguagem sem problemas.

A solução que encontrei foi adicionando o link ou img no meio do e-mail e quando ele for aberto teria a confirmação porém penso se não tem como fazer uma consulta com essa messageid no servidor de email.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, é importante você saber que é impossível descobrir se um usuário abriu um e-mail enviado pois o protocolo SMTP não provê uma maneira para que possamos identificar esta ação. O que podemos fazer, é colocar alguns "gatilhos" dentro do e-mail para tentar nos ajudar saber quando isso ocorreu (vou citar alguns casos que você especificou na sua dúvida também):

1. Colocar uma imagem oculta e quando o cliente estiver com a opção de visualizar html habilitada, a partir dessa imagem que geralmente vem com um parâmetro junto, você identifica que aquele e-mail foi aberto. Pode ocorrer do cliente não estar com a visualização do html habilitado e mesmo assim abrir seu e-mail e você nunca seria notificado.
2. Colocar um cabeçalho no e-mail para que o remetente seja notificado quando e-mail for lido. Feature famosa no final da década de 90 e inicio dos 00, porém, o cliente pode cancelar essa notificação manualmente.
3. Enviar um link no e-mail, forçando o cliente entrar na url para ler a mensagem (muito parecido com a ideia da opção 1)

Para incrementar suas funcionalidades de e-mail, você pode [consultar a documentação](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail) do plugin, quando você enviar o e-mail através do

```
transporter.sendMail(data, function(callback) {

});
```

você tem acesso ao objeto callback.info (entra outros atributos) que provê as seguintes variáveis:

- **messageId**: *most transports should* return the final Message-Id value used with this property (observe que should = deveria, portanto, não é garantido também)
- **envelope**: includes the envelope object for the message
- **accepted**: is an array returned by SMTP transports (includes recipient addresses that were accepted by the server)
- **rejected**: is an array returned by SMTP transports (includes recipient addresses that were rejected by the server)
- **pending**: is an array returned by Direct SMTP transport. Includes recipient addresses that were temporarily rejected together with the server response

Comment: Por estarmos em um site que segue a língua portuguesa, imagino que seria prudente que o senhor traduzisse os trechos em inglês para o português.

Comment: Aceitei como resposta! Obrigado.